# How to use the url template tag to point to diferrent classes within the admin

Tags: python, django

I would like to be able to use the django's `url` template tag in such a way that I could for example write:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:car' %}">Cars</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:motorbike' %}">Motorbikes</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:truck' %}">Trucks</a>
```

Each of those links would take me directly to the corresponding model class in the django admin.

This is how my `urls.py` looks right now:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^apirest/', include('apirest.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...,
    ...,
    url(r'^jsreverse/$', cache_page(3600)(urls_js), name='js-reverse'),
]
```

Comment: Well, reversing links to admin pages is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls); what problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_car_changelist' %}">Cars</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_motorbike_changelist' %}">Motorbikes</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_truck_changelist' %}">Trucks</a>
```

Where `myapp` is the name of the app each model comes from. There's more detail on how to reverse admin urls [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls).